# How to redirect linker errors without using redirection operator?

Tags: c, linux

[This question is not about fixing the error. But about redirecting it]

I have a program (C/linux) which displays error on the console due to missing shared library. It says "can't load library ...." . How can I redirect this output into a file ?

I tried this inside my program:

```
close(2);
open("/home/user/test.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
```

It correctly redirects the output generated from the program printfs. But the "can't load library ...." still comes on console!

I don't want to use the  > operator for this purpose. I want to do it from inside my program. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is generated by the loader, which happens before the program even starts. So there's nothing you can do from within a program that *doesn't even get to run* to influence the behaviour of the loader.

If you really need to fiddle with the file descriptors used by the shell, check out the `exec` shell command to close and redirect file descriptors permanently. That way you can get around using the redirection operator `>`, although that's arguably a far less tidy approach.

Comment: Got it. So loader is not executing in the process context. But what about run time errors like "... Symbol not found ..." which happens during runtime. Who generate the symbol not found kind of errors in the program ? Is it dynamic linker ?

Comment: If you're referring to `dlopen` etc., then those errors are created by the relevant library function (e.g. `libdl`); since those write to `stderr` from with your program, you should be able to control those.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a wrapper program. It could be a shell script. Do the redirection then try to run the original program.

A program cannot catch errors that happen to it before it even starts running. Library link happens before any other code runs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the message is generated before your program starts - so to redirect it, you'll have to use the 2> operator. Otherwise you'll have to use the dlopen... etc. calls to do the linking on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

try making sure that the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is correct.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify it. It is not about fixing the error. Error is okay for me. It is about redirecting it from the program itself

Answer (score 0):

that warnings & error mesages comes befor your program starts to work so only option is > operator

use this way

```
./a.out >&  filename
```